# Why I Can not Reverse Proxy Servlet in Apache

Tags: apache, servlets, struts, reverse-proxy

I have java web app which is deployed in tomcat, and in front end I have apache server.

This is my reverse proxy config in httpd.config for that servlet.

```
ProxyRequests Off    
ProxyPass /MyWebApp/MyServlet.do    http://localhost:8080/MyServlet.do  
ProxyPassReverse /MyWebApp/MyServlet.do     http://localhost:8080/MyServlet.do
```

Servlet Config in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.MyWebApp/MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have other proxypass setting for struts action url[I am Using struts framework], only the servlets are not working.

Comment: Does in work at localhost?

Comment: Why do you need a servlet?

Comment: @RomanC Yes it work in localhost

Comment: @AleksandrM Using servlet as a webservice for mobile app.

Comment: @SubashL How did you use Struts2, post `struts.xml`.

Comment: It only works in this link : http://localhost:8080/MyServlet.do That is why I have proxypass this URL which does not work : /MyWebApp/MyServlet.do

Comment: @RomanC If the answer is not what you expected, I am sorry I think I have not understand the question

Comment: @SubashL `.do` is not used with Struts2 by default, but you put [tag:struts2] on the question. That's why I have asked you to clarify the question, but you don't understand me.

Comment: @RomanC I am newbie to web development

Comment: @SubashL That's ok with SO, but if you want to ask a question you should learn first [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @RomanC I have edited the question.